# How do I change a variable in a Wordpress query with a select menu dropdown option and reload the WP query

Tags: wp-query, ajax, jquery

I'm implementing a drop down menu that is populated with brand names of products. It's populated dynamically with the title(s) from a wordpress custom post type (*axiss-brand*).

When the user selects the dropdown option / brand name the option will be stored as a variable for a value in a query of a different CPT (*axiss-dealer*). The query will display the product dealer(s) info that the brand is available from. The data includes, title, city, state, phone etc. All the data is from advanced custom fields.

I have the dropdown menu displaying the title / brand name properly. I have the query working properly displaying the custom field data. I'm using '**$brand**' as a WP query variable for the brand tile.

How do update the '**$brand**' WP query variable with the dropdown 'onchange' value and load / reload the updated query and content? I'm assuming with is an ajax issue. I'll probably fade the content in and out on load with jquery. Is this even the best way to handle this by using a variable in the query?

```
    //jQuery that captures the selected option in the dropdown  
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#brand-select').on('change', function() {
            var selectValue = $(this).val();
            alert(selectValue);
        });
     });

      // The drop down menu
      <form>
        <select name="brand" id="brand-select">
            <?php
                $args = array(
                    'post_type' => 'axiss-brand',
                    'posts_per_page' => -1,
                    'orderby' => 'title',
                    'order' => 'ASC',
                );
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                $sobe = get_posts($args);
                foreach ($sobe as $post){
                    setup_postdata($post);
                    $brand_name = get_the_title();            
            ?>
             <option value=" <?php echo $brand_name ?> " > <?php echo $brand_name ?> </option>                                                                     
         <?php }?>
                <?php wp_reset_postdata();?>          
        </select>
   </form>
       // The wordpress query
       $args1 = array(                                      
            'post_type' => 'axiss-dealer', 
            'post_status' => 'publish',                                       
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'meta_key'          => 'state',
            'orderby'           => 'meta_value',
            'order'             => 'ASC',
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation'      => 'and',
                array(
                    'key'     => 'dealer_brands',
                    'value'   => $brand,
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                ),
                array(
                    'key'     => 'dealer_tier',
                    'value'   => 'Certified',
                    'compare' => 'LIKE',
                    
                ),
            ),
        );
  // Displaying the query
  <?php $dealer_query1 = new WP_Query( $args1 ); ?>
    <?php if( $dealer_query1->have_posts() ): ?>
        <ul>
         <?php while( $dealer_query1->have_posts() ) : $dealer_query1->the_post(); ?>
            <li>
                   <?php the_title(); ?></p>
                   <?php the_field('address');?>
                   <?php the_field('city');?>
                   <?php the_field('state');?>
                   <?php the_field('zip_code');?>
                   <?php the_field('phone');?>
                   <?php the_field('dealer_tier');?>
                   <?php the_field('dealer_brands');?>
                   <?php the_field('state');?>
           </li>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
      </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```